# Needing help adding a variable in a sql query within Python

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am trying to write a while loop within my sql query in python but have had some trouble. The variable I want is my 'count' to be included in the records when inserting values.

The code below is what I have already tried:

```
count = 0
while count < 10:
    cursor.execute('''           
               INSERT INTO Table_Test1 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
               VALUES ('Test1','Test2', '''"count"''')
               ''')
    count  = count + 1

conn.commit()
```

The values going into my table are:

```
(1, 'Test1', 'Test2', '"count"')
.
.
(10, 'Test1', 'Test2', '"count"')
```

What I want is:

```
(1, 'Test1', 'Test2', '0')
.
.
(10, 'Test1', 'Test2', '9')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a formatted string literal (f-string), so for yours, you could do:

```
while count < 10:
    cursor.execute(f'''           
               INSERT INTO Table_Test1 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
               VALUES ('Test1','Test2', {count})
               ''')
```

Comment: @MichaelRyan glad I could help! The addition of f-strings in Python 3.6 really makes things like that easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use a query parameter:

```python
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Table_Test1 (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES ('Test1','Test2', ?)", count)
```